# Offset is undefined. What is offset?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting a warning about "undefined offset = 0". What am I doing wrong?

This is my controller:

```
function document_data()
{
  $this->load->library('upload');

  $files = $_FILES;
  $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
  $tax_name=$this->session->userdata['doc_proff'];
  $tax_cid=array();

  foreach($tax_name as $key=>$value)
  {
    $tax_cid[]=$this->Tax_model->get_id($value);
  }

  foreach($tax_cid as $k=>$v) {
    $new[$k] = $v[0];
  }

  //var_dump($k);die('gugu');
  foreach($new as $k=>$v) {
    $tax_id[$k] = $v['tax_id'];
  }
  //var_dump($v);die('gugu');

  $this->upload->overwrite = true;

  for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
  {
    $ext=explode(".", $files['userfile']['name'][$i]);
    $file_name=$_POST["doc_title"][$i].".".$ext[1];                                                      
    $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $file_name;
    $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];                    

    $empid=$this->session->userdata['empid'];
    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
      $this->load->view('doc_upload', $error);
    }

    $data=array(
      'doc_status' => 1,
      'doc_title'  => $_POST["doc_title"][$i],
      'doc_link'   => $file_name
    );

    $this->Tax_model->update_tax_submit($empid,$data,$tax_id[$i]);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Data added successfully.</p>");
  }
}
```

This is my model:

```
public function get_id($name)
{
  $this->db->select('tax_id');
  $this->db->where('tax_name',$name);
  $query=$this->db->get('tax_saving');
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

The warning occurs on the following line of my controller:

```
$new[$k] = $v[0];
```

Everything seems to be working fine. I just want to get rid of this warning. What should I do?

Comment: IF some one can explain what is offset it ll b great

Comment: you are never initiliazing the variable $new, so when you want to set a value for index $k, PHP warns/notices (dont know) that this offset does not exist. offset is the key value of an array

Comment: `Offset` means how far you are away from a certain point. For arrays, offset means how far you are away from the start of the array, hence 0 places , 1 place, 2 places, 3 places and so on. If you have an offset 0 being unavailable, that is not an array then

Comment: thank hanky panky.yes that is not an array,that is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already split index and value with `$k => $v`. Just use for get value: `$v`

```
foreach($tax_cid as $k => $v) {
  $new[$k] = $v;
}
```

You array dump:

```
array(4) 
{
 [0]=> array(0) { } 
 [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tax_id"]=> string(2) "10" } } 
 [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tax_id"]=> string(2) "11" } } 
 [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tax_id"]=> string(2) "14" } } 
}
```

In fact, your `$new[$k] = $v[0];` usage was right.

Cause of error, your first index is empty. Check your result from tax_model.

And why you use double foreach? You dont need below `foreachs`

```
  foreach($tax_cid as $k=>$v) {
    $new[$k] = $v[0];
  }

  //var_dump($k);die('gugu');
  foreach($new as $k=>$v) {
    $tax_id[$k] = $v['tax_id'];
  }
```

You can use something like with one foreach:

```
foreach($tax_name as $key=>$value)
{
   $result = $this->Tax_model->get_id($value);
   $tax_cid[] = $result[0]['tax_id'];
}
```

Comment: No bora im still getting that message. but if add your code i ll get error of undefined index tax_id

Comment: can you paste `var_dump($tax_cid)` to question `$tax_cid` array?

Comment: i am geting these values
array(4) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tax_id"]=> string(2) "10" } } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tax_id"]=> string(2) "11" } } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tax_id"]=> string(2) "14" } } } shiv

Comment: bora thnkx for the help buti did a mistake on my excel shit thts y i was getting error..now its fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

It is showing error may be `$v` array does not have an index 0. First of all make sure that if `$v` is an array then use indexes and use appropriate indexes while assigning it and offset is index of an array.

Comment: $v is a string MR suresh.